# Exactly three distinct valued metric.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, metric-spaces

> The discrete metric $d_0$ can take two values $0$ and $1$. Can a metric
>   function $d_X$ on a set $X$ attain exactly *three* distinct values?

Going through the route of actually finding a metric instead of disproving one exists, I tried finding a metric which has values $0$, $a$ and $b$. But by trying to define it in a similar way as the discrete metric, I had a hard time finding one that could satisfy the three requirements to be a metric.

Disproving it on the other hand sounds pretty easy tho, by just taking $x, y, z \in X$, I set the two values to random distances like $d_X(x, y) = a = d_X(y,x)$ , $d_X(x, z) = b = d_X(z, x)$ and finally $d_X(y, z) = c = d_X(z, y)$, with $c$ being either $a$ or $b$. Applying this to the triangle inequality gives us.

$d_X(x, z) \leq d_X(x, y) + d_X(y,z)$ 
$d_X(x, y) \leq d_X(x, z) + d_X(z,y)$ 
$d_X(y, z) \leq d_X(y, x) + d_X(x,z)$

Which gives us the linear inequalities:

$b \leq a + c$ 
$a \leq b + c$ 
$c \leq a + b$

This cannot hold if $c$ is either $a$ or $b$.
Is this proof correct? And more importantly, isn't there a better proof, because this sounds like a very inefficient proof.

Comment: Your proof does not work. Once you say that $x \in X$, but then you say $x=a$ or $x=b$ (meaning that $x \in \Bbb{R}_{\ge 0}$), so you are contradicting yourself if $X$ and $\Bbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ are disjoint. Another thing you say is "this cannot hold if $x$ is either $a$ or $b$": this is not correct, because you are not considering the case $a=b=x$ or the case $x=a=2b$.

Comment: I did consider those cases $a = b = x$, but that case ends up with a metric that does not have exactly three distinct values. And yeah I now realize I used the letter $x$ for two different things, I'll edit that in the question by using $c$ to show the difference.

Comment: Your other case does hold tho, can't believe I looked over that, thanks for the critique and your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X$ be any set with a partition into two nonempty disjoint subsets $A$ and $B$:
$$X=A \cup B \ \ \ \wedge \ \ \ A \cap B = \emptyset$$
Define
$$d_X(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0 & \mbox{if }x=y \\
1 & \mbox{if } x,y \in A \\
1 & \mbox{if } x,y \in B \\
2 & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

This is a distance defined on $X$ with only three values.

Comment: Interesting, can your argument be easily generalized to metrics taking $n$ values?

Comment: Yes of course. You have to consider a partition of $X$ into $n$ classes $A_1, \dots , A_n$. Then define $d(x_i, x_j)= |i-j|+1$ where $x_i \in A_i$ and $x_j \in A_j$.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the space of 3 points $\{x,y,z\}$ with the metric
$d:=\begin{cases}
d(x,y)=1\\
d(x,z)=2\\
d(y,z)=1\\
\end{cases}$

satisfies the requirement too.